# MongoDB PHP driver on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, mongodb

I have installed MongoDB PHP driver on Ubuntu 14.04 using this command

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

and it installed the driver but an older version which is 1.4, the problem is I need latest one, which is 1.6. I already tried this command.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongodb
```

but getting error no package found. Can someone help installing latest mongodb php driver on ubuntu 14.04

I followed this link as well and installed pecl extension but nothing worked http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2013/02/the-easy-way-to-install-the-mongodb-php-driver-on-ubuntu-1204

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-cli php-pear -y  
sudo pecl install mongo
```

As shown here: http://blog.programster.org/debian-8-install-mongodb-php-driver/ (I've tested on ubuntu 14 and it worked)